# EF Core fails in Windows Service but works in console app

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-core, windows-services

I created a windows service, which uses EF Core 3.1.32 to access some data. I had to fall back to 3.1.32, because the service also hosts a WCF service, and I am stuck with .NET Framework 4.8. All later EF Core versions require NET6, on which I will not get the WCF service to run.

Now, if I start the windows service in a console app (.NET Framework 4.8), everything works fine. I can request data through the WCF service from the management app with no problem. As soon as I install the windows service through the InstallUtil tool, it works fine and opens the WCF service host. However, when I request any data, I get the exception

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ... "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" ...`

as soon as the DbContext is created.

When I force `System.Runtime` to be loaded, the exception changes to `TypeLoadException for IAsyncDisposable`.

I am pretty confused, as I expected that the `IAsyncDisposable` interface would be handled by `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` in EF Core. That assembly also is present, but in the windows service it appears no to be used.

Please help :) I am terribly stuck since some days

For clarity, I might have to add that, all functions of the entire service are working fine, either when running as console app, and as Windows service. Just the EF Core context fails.

Comment: Is that on the same machine? Are all binding redirects in place?

Comment: The IAsyncDisposable interface you want to implement in EF Core. Have you tried other ways to implement it ?

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes, it is the same code and compilation, running on the same machine on Win11.

Comment: @Jiayao Yes, I tried. I implemented Dispose, AsyncDispose (AsyncDisposeCore) exactly as proposed by Microsoft into the respective Context implementations. Nothing changed. For a test, I simply created a `new DbContext()`, with the same result. As soon as the constructor is called, the Exception is thrown.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an EF core authentication problem?

Comment: @Jiayao No, I suppose. There is nothing taking place in the EF Core parts of the code, so far. As mentioned in my previous comment, just creating a new DbContext raises the FileNotFoundException. No connection is opened, nor any query is invoked. And the same code runs smoothly in the console app. Just starting it as a service (by using the InstallUtil utility) creates these problems. I am really stuck... Could there be differences or limitations in the runtime?